# Manipulating variables in jQuery to be displayed in html code

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, ajax, jquery, array

I make a request in Ajax at the click of the button passing the id of a product to a controller and it passes to the helper. In the helper, through this id of the product, I add it to the cart, but that does not matter much on that issue. In this helper, I create an `array` with data and give a return on it and then the controller returns me that array. When I give an `alert` in the `array`, specifying the position of the array, it shows me the value. I wanted to display this `array` value in `HTML` code (in case it would be in h1 that I put in append).

**Ajax request:**

```
        function addCartao(product_id){
            alert("entrou");
            alert(product_id);
            $j.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('fol_carousel/ajax/teste') ?>",
              data: {
                product_id: product_id
              },
              dataType: 'json',
              cache : false,
              beforeSend: function () {
                alert("beforeSend");
              },
              success: function (retorno) {
                alert('success');
                alert(retorno['name']);
                $j('.item-custom').append('<h1 class="product-name">(
The exact position value of the array should be displayed here)</h1>');
              },
              complete: function () {
                alert("complete");
              },
              error: function (x,y,z) {
                alert("error");
                alert(x);
                alert(y);
                alert(z);
                window.location.reload();
                history.go(0);
                window.location.href=window.location.href;
              }
          });
        }
```

**Controller code:**

```
$product_id = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
$dados = Mage::helper('fol_carousel/cartao')->addCustom($product_id);
echo json_encode($dados);
```

**Array I create in the helper:**

```
$dados['name'] = 'Teste';
$dados['price'] = "2.99";
return $dados;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found to the problem was by changing the `.append()` function of the ajax request, concatenating with the position of the array in the necessary place for it to be displayed.

**Ajax request code with change:**

```
        function addCartao(product_id){
            alert("entrou");
            alert(product_id);
            $j.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('fol_carousel/ajax/teste') ?>",
              data: {
                product_id: product_id
              },
              dataType: 'json',
              cache : false,
              beforeSend: function () {
                alert("beforeSend");
              },
              success: function (retorno) {
                alert('success');
                alert(retorno['name']);
                $j('.item-custom').append('<h1 class="product-name">' + retorno['name'] + '</h1>');
              },
              complete: function () {
                alert("complete");
              },
              error: function (x,y,z) {
                alert("error");
                alert(x);
                alert(y);
                alert(z);
                window.location.reload();
                history.go(0);
                window.location.href=window.location.href;
              }
          });
        }
```